# Send_file aws s3 carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, carrierwave

I want to download a file uploaded on aws s3:

**controller**

```
def download
    send_file my_file.url
end
```

Actually I have tried all code found in similar posts:

```
send_file open(my_file.url).read
```

also without read. Nothing works

Comment: No I didn't manage to figure it out :)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be to directly read from your carrierwave object and use send_data as opposed to send_file. You'll get the added benefit of carrierwave using it's own local cache if your file exists there as well.

Anyways you could try using send_data with your example like this:

```
send_data(my_file.file.read, filename: 'your_txt_file.txt', type: 'text/plain', disposition: 'attachment', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096')
```

You should specify **disposition: 'attachment'** if you're wanting the file to be directly downloaded by the user, or if you would prefer the file to render within the users own browser, you could use **disposition: 'inline'**

Answer (score 1):

## controller

```
def download
  redirect_to my_file.file.url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution I ended up using for pfd, and zip files. Have not figured it out with images/png or jpeg. My model's name was Import. Hope this helps a bit.

View

```
<%= link_to 'Download', import.image.url %>
```

Controller

```
def download_file
  @import = Import.find(params[:id])
  send_file(@import.image.path,
      :disposition => 'attachment',
      :url_based_filename => false)
end
```

Routes

```
resources :imports do
  collection do
    get 'download'      
  end
end
```